# load json to pyspark rdd TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable

Tags: python, json, pyspark, spark-streaming

I run the following codes to read json to rdd and dataframe in pyspark and got error `"TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable"`

just read these data to rdd, with pattern as following:

> expected rdd data pattern in dataframe

```
a       b     c    e
000011  1-2   239  0
000011  1-3   271  0
```

> python codes

```
import requests
import json

a = "{'OUT': '000011@@@;1-2=239=0;1-3=271=0;1-4=266=0;1-5=103=0;1-6=682=0;1-7=81=0;1-8=389=0;1-9=155=0;1-10=28=0;1-11=64=0;1-12=268=0;1-13=335=0;1-14=999=0;2-3=257=0;2-4=294=0;2-5=96=0;2-6=999=0;2-7=81=0;2-8=372=0;2-9=163=0'}"

a = json.dumps(a)
a = json.loads(a)

def convert_single_object_per_line(json_list):
    json_string = ""
    for line in json_list:
        json_string += json.dumps(line) + "\n"
    return json_string

def parse_dataframe(json_data):
    r = convert_single_object_per_line(json_data)
    mylist = []
    for line in r.splitlines():
        mylist.append(line)
    rdd = sc.parallelize(mylist)
    df = sqlContext.jsonRDD(rdd)
    return df

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")

rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
df = parse_dataframe(rdd)
```

> Error message:

```
"TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable"
```

Comment: You probably want to collect like this:     ```r = convert_single_object_per_line(json_data.collect())```

Comment: dear, @RobertKossendey it seem not work error msg = `'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'collect'`